# When i call package.function within a procedure and function return value in cursor, how can i store these value in procedure variable in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

The PKG_LIST_LOG.abc (package.function) return a value like {<PR=100: ORA-01403: no data ,SC=ORA-01403: no data found,PSC=sp_ls :LA,EXEC_DATE=04-MAY-23>,} so how can i store this information in the below procedure and print the result.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIST_LOG(name VARCHAR2, id VARCHAR2, label VARCHAR2)
IS
    v_query VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_result VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN   
    CASE label
        WHEN 'abc' THEN
          v_query := 'SELECT PKG_LIST_LOG.abc('''||name||''','''||id||''','''||label||''') FROM DUAL';
          OPEN v_cursor FOR v_query;
          FETCH v_cursor INTO v_result;
--            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query INTO v_result;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_result);
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID PARAMETERS');
    END CASE;
END;
/
```

Comment: this error message shown Error report -
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CURSOR
ORA-06512: at "LIST_LOG", line 11
ORA-06512: at line 1
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understood it, you should just put result of the `abc` function into `v_cursor`.

As I don't have your tables nor data (and you didn't post any additional info), here's an example based on Scott's sample schema.

Function returns ref cursor:

```
SQL> create or replace function abc(p_deptno in number, p_job in varchar2)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select ename, sal
  7    from emp
  8    where deptno = p_deptno
  9      and job = p_job;
 10    return rc;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.
```

Procedure calls that function; note line #7 - that's what you should do; there's nothing *dynamic* in your code so you don't have / need to compose a `select` statement which calls the function, nor should you open a cursor - just use what function returned:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure list_log(p_deptno in number, p_job in varchar2)
  2  is
  3    v_cursor sys_refcursor;
  4    v_ename  emp.ename%type;
  5    v_sal    emp.sal%type;
  6  begin
  7    v_cursor := abc(p_deptno, p_job);
  8    loop
  9      fetch v_cursor into v_ename, v_sal;
 10      exit when v_cursor%notfound;
 11      dbms_output.put_line(v_ename ||' '|| v_sal);
 12    end loop;
 13    close v_cursor;
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec list_log(20, 'CLERK');
SMITH 840
ADAMS 1100

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Is that output correct? Looks like it is:

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp where deptno = 20 and job = 'CLERK';

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
SMITH             840
ADAMS            1100

SQL>
```

Comment: create or replace PROCEDURE LIST_LOG(name in VARCHAR2, id in VARCHAR2, label in VARCHAR2)
IS
    v_query VARCHAR2(4000);
    v_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
    v_result VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN   
    CASE label
        WHEN 'abc' THEN
          v_query := 'SELECT PKG_LOG.abc('''||name||''','''||id||''','''||label||''') FROM DUAL';
          OPEN v_cursor FOR v_query;
          FETCH v_cursor INTO v_result;
--            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query INTO v_result;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_result);
    ELSE
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INVALID PARAMETERS');
    END CASE;
END;

Comment: i just want to hold and display the result from package.function return into the procedure  using case when, and package.function return result as a cursor